# How to generate Devise views in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Devise's documentation says to enter the following to generate the views:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

However, when I enter that, rails gives me usage instructions:

```
new-host-6:test4 scott$ rails generate devise:views
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
  etc
```

Comment: Are you running this command from the application root???

Comment: @MohdAnas - yes I am, the application is called test4, you can see I'm in the test4 directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was using Ruby 1.9.3 with a Rails 3.2 gemset in the Rails 4 project directory. Everything works fine after I did a `rvm use 2.0.0@rails4`

Comment: Thanks for coming back and leaving the solution here. Here is a helpful note for others: 1) to see current rvm ruby: `rvm list`
2) to see current gemset: `rvm gemset list` 3) to change the gemset: `rvm gemset use XXX`